# Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Resource<TypeVariable(T)> was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, type-mismatch

Creating a simple notes app to practice MVVM architecture, where we upload to note to Firebase Firestore.

Resource.kt

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String? = null) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
}
```

RepositoryUtil.kt

```
inline fun <T> safeCall(action: () -> Resource<T>): Resource<T> {
    return try {
        action()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Resource.Error(e.message ?: "Something went wrong!")
    }
}
```

MainRepository.kt

```
interface MainRepository {
    suspend fun addNote(text: String): Resource<Note>
    suspend fun getNotes(): Resource<List<Note>>
}
```

DefaultMainRepository.kt

```
@ActivityScoped
class DefaultMainRepository : MainRepository {

    private val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val notes = firestore.collection("notes")

    override suspend fun addNote(text: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        safeCall {}
    }
}
```

Getting this error once I add safeCall{} under addNote() in DefaultMainRepository.kt.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Resource<TypeVariable(T)> was expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't providing a lambda to `safeCall` that returns a resource.  The empty `safeCall {}` is really `safeCall( {  Unit  } )`, but you defined `safeCall` to accept a `action: () -> Resource<T>`.

Try temporarily replacing `safeCall {}` with `safeCall { Resource.Error("Test") }` and see if that resolves the compiler error.